# Border-image with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a div that uses a linear gradient as a border-image to give it some gradient borders

```
<div class = "gradborders" id="mydiv" runat="server">
..various elements...
</div>
....
....
.gradborders{ 
border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(20,20,20,0.7) 5%,  rgba(90,90,90,0.5) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%) 8 stretch;
border-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(20,20,20,0.7) 5%,  rgba(90,90,90,0.5) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%) 8 stretch;
border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(20,20,20,0.7) 5%,  rgba(90,90,90,0.5) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%) 8 stretch;
border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(20,20,20,0.7) 5%,  rgba(90,90,90,0.5) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%) 8 stretch;}
```

and I want the corners rounded. I tried the standard way by adding this to gradborders:

```
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
```

but no dice. I even tried using the AJAX Rounded Corner extender on the div which I was sure would work but that also did not work. Any ideas??

Comment: See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53037637).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f3bm/) will do:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gradborders">hi</div>
</div>
```

and

```
.container{border-radius: 10px;overflow:hidden;}
.gradborders{ 
-webkit-border-image: url("http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1686_520555094669668_1347475803_n.jpg") 8;}
```

Comment: strangely enough that only rounds the top left corner

Comment: never mind, this works...I actually had some extra elements in my style that I didn`t need which were preventing it from working (border-width and background-clip: padding-box;). Once I removed those, this worked

Comment: Too bad you only used the `-webkit-` prefix and an image that didn’t persist.

Comment: @dakab: any image will do

Comment: @DouglasDenhartog: That's self-evident. The critique targeted your broken Fiddle and its Webkit-specificity (the question looking for a generic answer).

Comment: @dakab, feel free to participate in the community by editing fiddles and answers with updates :)

Comment: @DouglasDenhartog: [Editing is encouraged for some reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (“spelling mistakes”, “without changing it”), but not to assume the author’s work and certainly not to interfere with the author’s intention, which in this case obviously did not encompass platform-agnosticism.