# Is it possible to create a gradient border on a CIRCLE with css3?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have an background image in shape of a circle. Have given it a yellow border. I would like to change the border to a gradient from yellow to white. I have seen many examples with square borders but none applied to circles. Here's my code:

```css
.Profileimage{
  background-image: url("images/profilePic.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius:50px;
  -moz-border-radius:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(252,238,33); 
}
```

```html
<div class="Profileimage"></div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: this would use the `border-image` property, which can't be combined with `border-radius`. the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient) go in depth about why that is, and also suggest a technique you could use to spoof the effect.

Answer (score 17):

This Is Your Answer:

```css
#cont{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, crimson 0%, #f90 100%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#box{
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this?

```
.Profileimage{
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(252,238,33), rgb(255,255,255));
  -webkit-border-radius:50px;
  -moz-border-radius:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.Profileimage:after{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url("images/profilePic.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you can just set the background to the gradient, and then position an element over the top (here I'm using the 'after' pseudo selector)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ue88pu6/1/

Comment: the jsfiddle link you've provided doesn't reflect the code you've posted here -- double check your link.

Comment: Looks pretty good I must say. Didn't think this could be done with CSS.

Comment: awesome-I like that look. very nice-thanks so much...I will try both

Comment: Very efficient, Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question is already old, but i just had the same problem and i could fix it. 
The trick is to wrap your div into another div.

```css
.gradient-wrapper { padding: 10px; border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block;
  background: yellow; // As fallback for browsers which do not support gradient
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, white); 
  background: -o-linear-gradient(yellow, white); 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(yellow, white); 
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, white); 
}

#maincircle { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #424242; border-radius: 50%; }
```

```html
<div class="gradient-wrapper">
  <div id="maincircle">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Result of Code Snippet]

Hope this helped!