# Border-image with border-radius - but without border-color overlay

Tags: css, border, border-image

I want to create a transparent round button, on click it should have a striped border. I would like to do this with HTML, CSS, or if necessary java-script.

Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/chrichrichri/a9dpg582/38/

```
border-radius: 50px;
```

combined with:

```
border-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-40deg, yellow, yellow 10%, orange 11%, orange 20%, yellow 21%), 
    -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-40deg, yellow, yellow 10%, orange 11%, orange 20%, yellow 21%), 
    repeating-linear-gradient(-40deg, yellow, yellow 10%, orange 11%, orange 20%, yellow 21%);
```

So far I tested it in Firefox - the border image considers the border-radius, but there is always a border-color overlay - If I have 50% transparency, I see the strips and the selected color - but I want just the strips… if I use transparent/rgba(0,0,0,0) the border is not displayed at all. Why? I would be happy if somebody can explain what is going on here :-)

A similar topic has been discussed already 7 years ago - but the solutions given there work only for elements with a solid filling - ok, you can add an svg ellipse instead of the border - but maybe by now there is a simpler solution. ([Possible to use border-radius together with a border-image which has a gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient))

Comment: Please post the code you're having problems with, preferably in a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::before` and `::after` classes

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9dpg582/78/)

Comment: But this does work only for solid elements and not for transparent ones, or?

Comment: sofar the only solution for a transparent button using pseudoclasses I found would be a "life ring"-version: https://jsfiddle.net/chrichrichri/1bnv8sza/3/
- this nearly woult also work without pseudoclass - with a dashed border and a radial gradient which is transparent until it reaches the border - unfortunately you cannot control the background repeat sufficiently - so the pseudoclass is necessary.

- It seems using an svg is the only real option for what I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/chrichrichri/bqsnpn5k/76/