# Add image border to circular div

Tags: css, border-image

I want to set an image around  a round div as border. The round div is created by `border-radius:50%`.

CSS:

```css
.circ {
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 15px solid transparent;
 padding: 15px;
 border-image-source: url(border.png);
 border-image-repeat: round;
 border-image-slice: 30;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="circ"></div>
```

This is my div:

[image: div without border]

Border:

[image: border image]

And finally I want this:

[image: div with image border]

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient

Comment: look at the way that border-image works:https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Comment: this way only works for border-image, but i want to make round-border-image. it seems that these two don't work when used together.