# Round image border instead of square

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Instead of square I want it around the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oXeF.png)

So I am wanting to change my red circular border into an image. however it keeps coming out as a square or rectangle.

I have managed to find this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3rLa/1/) and amended it to show what is [going wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/JACRunner/68y92qgj/8/)

```
.line {
  z-index: 10;
  border: 12px solid #FF0000;
  /*border-image:  url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3c/bf/5e/3cbf5eabbde02cad7a36c47d408b5e58.jpg') 360 round;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I am hoping to get the border image to wrap around the inner circular image instead i get either pillars or a square/rectangle.

EDIT: the proposed duplicate primarily focuses on adding a gradient within the border. I am simply wanting to overlay my imge url ontop of the border.

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve is not possible. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient .

Comment: a gradient is considered as an image so the duplicate is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this link for detail,
https://jsfiddle.net/jignashagpatel/q2uvapLc/2/

```
.avatar{
    background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png');
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

   <img class="avatar" src="http://cs409019.vk.me/v409019863/1b6/09FPiv6Nr5A.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 1):

- added box-sizing property to make sure that the border size and
  padding/margins wont be a problem
- the border radius must be half the width and the height plus you must
  always declare the width and the height.
- Here is the working CSS from your fiddle after modifying it
  EDIT: Can you clarify your seconed (gradient) question?

```css
.avatar { 
width: 128px;
height: 128px;
margin: 10px;
border: 10px solid red;
border-radius: 50%;
box-sizing: border-radius;
}
```

```html
<img class="avatar" src="http://cs409019.vk.me/v409019863/1b6/09FPiv6Nr5A.jpg" />
```

Comment: where you have red i want that area to be a linked image. however when you link the image, it reverts back to a rectangle.