# How to apply a gradient to a table row border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gradient

[image: Images]

On the header i used a pseudo-element to create this gradient border.
This is my code:

```
.wrapper::before {
    z-index: 1000;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 106px;
    inset: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2px; 
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,#4757e370,#5b2bdf70); 
  }
```

Now i want the same gradient on my table row borders. How can i achieve this? Somehow i can't apply pseudo-elements on my td-childs. Sadly there is no way known to me on how to apply gradients on borders. Somebody knows how to do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey there, can you complete the code with HTML and also reproduce a demo out of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very similar to what you have done with pseudo elements if that's working for you. You just have to set the `tr` elements to display as block

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: hsl(231deg 23% 11%);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

table {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  --br: 20px;
  --border-size: 4px;
  
  display: block;
  height: 1rem;
  margin: 0.7rem;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--br);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

tr::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: calc(-1 * var(--border-size));
  border-radius: var(--br);
  background:linear-gradient(90deg,#4757e370,#5b2bdf70); 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
<table>
```

It's worth checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963/possible-to-use-border-radius-together-with-a-border-image-which-has-a-gradient) as well which might provide a more in depth explanation.

It's also worth mentioning, when I am creating tables I rarely rely on table styling anymore, and will usually default to using a grid layout style and this makes gaps and the sort much more manageable.