Linear gradient borders

I want to achieve this linear gradient borders using CSS
I tried adding this:
.demo-mode {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 62.72%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 100vw #111026;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 24px;
}


But this is showing me left left and right borders and the bottom border not the top one.


.wrapper {
padding: 20px;
background: #111026;
}
.demo-mode {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 62.72%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 100vw #111026;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px
}
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="demo-mode"></div>
</div>




Could you adapt this answer to apply to your use case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53037637/12571484

You can fix it by adding:
background-origin: border-box;


border-box
The background is positioned relative to the border box.

Here you can find more info about background-origin.
Example:


.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #111026;
}

.demo-mode {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 62.72%);
  background-origin: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100vw #111026;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="demo-mode"></div>
</div>




Thank you this works, I also edited my question and added another case that maybe you can help
